# ObservableObject array not updating

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject

In the following example, I'm trying to display a list of objects.

`Object` has a title that changes from "old title" to "new title" asynchronously in the `init()`

`AllObjects` holds an array of `Object`s and asynchronously adds them in the `init()`

`ContentView` displays the title of each object

```
class Object: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var title: String = "old title"
    
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.title = "new title"
        }
    }
}

class AllObjects: ObservableObject {

    @Published var allObjects: [Object] = []
    
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.allObjects.append(Object())
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var allObjects = AllObjects()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(allObjects.allObjects, id: \.title) { obj in
                Text(obj.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to have the "new title" displayed, but it isn't updating the UI when the title is changed. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Nesting `ObservableObject` is not a good idea at all, make your `Object` a struct and this will work out of the box.
There are many examples of this on SO and the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because changes in Object are not forwarded to AllObjects.
Therefore the observedObject doesn't receive any changes and the view stay still.

To fix that you can listen to changes on object and forward them to AllObject like that :

```
class AllObjects: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var allObjects: [Object] = []
    
    var objectStorage: [AnyCancellable] = []
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
            guard let self else {return}

            let object = Object()
            object.objectWillChange.sink {
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }.store(in: &self.objectStorage)

            self.allObjects.append(object)            
        }
    }
}
```

[Edit] here is an explanation why your code doesn't work :

`allObjects` is an array of object, so it holds reference to the object.

`allObject` triggers an update when you add, remove, or switch  objects from it, but when one object content change, the array doesn't, since the reference didn't change.

It's the value that changed, not the address. Thus no update of the array

Comment: Thanks! Why doesn't the `@Published` in `Object` forward changes to `AllObjects` even though `@Published` forwards `AllObjects` changes to `ContentView`?